# C++ unable to open file by passing string or c_str() as reference

Tags: c++, string, constructor, fstream, c-strings

first post sorry if messy. I looked around for an answer to this and I tried using c_str() but that solution wasn't working. The problem I'm having is that this program triggers the !inFile if statement each time I run it. This program came from a textbook I have and I can't figure out why it isn't creating the files. I've tried using c_str(), I've tried typing in "foo.txt" for the file name, but nothing is working. If anybody can help thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class Encryption
{
protected:
    ifstream inFile;
    ofstream outFile;
public:
    Encryption(const string& inFileName, const string& outFileName);
    virtual ~Encryption();
    virtual char transform(char ch) const = 0;
    virtual void encrypt() final;
};

Encryption::Encryption(const string& inFileName, const string& outFileName)
{
    inFile.open(inFileName.c_str());
    outFile.open(outFileName.c_str());
    if (!inFile)
    {
        cout << "The file " << inFileName << " cannot be opened.";
        exit(1);
    }
    if (!outFile)
    {
        cout << "The file " << outFileName << " cannot be opened.";
        exit(1);
    }
}

Encryption:: ~Encryption()
{
    inFile.close();
    outFile.close();
}

void Encryption::encrypt()
{
    char ch;
    char transCh;
    inFile.get(ch);
    while (!inFile.fail())
    {
        transCh = transform(ch);
        outFile.put(transCh);
        inFile.get(ch);
    }
}

class SimpleEncryption : public Encryption
{
public:
    char transform(char ch) const override
    {
        return ch + 1;
    }
    SimpleEncryption(const string& inFileName, const string& outFileName) : Encryption(inFileName, outFileName)
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    string infileName, outFileName;
    cout << "name of file to encrypt: ";
    cin >> infileName;
    cout << "enter file to write to: ";
    cin >> outFileName;
    SimpleEncryption cipher(infileName, outFileName);
    cipher.encrypt();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It worked for me.  I compiled it.  For the first prompt, I typed in `dog.txt` (which I had made prior, says `Hello world`), and the second prompt `cat.txt`.  The `dog.txt` file was opened, the `cat.txt` file was created and written to, and contained the expected "encrypted" data.

Comment: I forgot to create the file before hand. Thank you for this, and for not telling me I'm an idiot

Comment: :-)  There are many ways in which the code or the build or the environment can cause things to go awry.

Comment: Sorry to bug you again but I made a some text files now to try and get this to work and it's still giving me the error. Do I have to save the files in a special folder? Is my compiler being weird? I'm not very good at opening files so I'm probably doing something stupid

Comment: How are you compiling the code?  How are you executable the program?  Is your current working directory for executable the program the same as the directory that has your text file?

Comment: Forgot to put it in the right file. It's working now sorry for being annoying